# How to make mapping from JSON array in RestKit

Tags: ios, json, restkit

I have mapping case with array of elements for specific field as the below example.I made relationship between Hotel & amenities but i can't get the values (A,B,C) because it didn't have identifier name.What is the correct value can set it in XXX to do mapping for name

```
JSON :

 "hotel":{
 property_amenities":["A","B","C"]
 }

Mapping :
 [hotelDetailEntityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
@"XXX"               : @"name", 
}];
```

Comment: Try to explain yourself better please

Comment: Can you put your real code to see what exactly are you doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution as the below code.

This is correct mapping :
 [hotelDetailEntityMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"name"]];

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's deserialized:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];

dict[@"property_amenities"][0] -> A

dict[@"property_amenities"][1] -> B
```

Comment: I used the RestKit framework how i can get the values ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to get A, B and C, Then you'll need to do this:

```
//Assume you have in a NSDicionary dictionary your JSON, then:
NSArray * propertyAmenities = dictionary[@"property_amenities"];

NSLog(@"%@", propertyAmenities[0])); // You get A
```

Editted:

If you haven't had you json in a nsdictionary, take a look of the answer below of mine from @Grzegorz Krukowski